# jQuery fileDownload plugin doesn't show popup window, how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery for my frontend part of an application (backend runs on Flask) and I needed a plugin for displaying some kind of information to user while he's waiting for a file to be served to him (and I also need to work with older versions of IE, which is why I've decided to use [this plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/)).

Unfortunately I haven't been able to do anything with it due to some weird JS errors I'm getting (screens and my example code below).

Example server-side code:

```
from flask import Flask, send_file, render_template
import os
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def mainRoute():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/filesfordl/file.txt', methods=['GET'])
def fileRoute():
    sleep(5) # time for window to appear
    fileResponse = send_file(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'filesfordl/file.txt'), as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='file.txt')
    fileResponse.set_cookie('fileDownload', 'true')
    return fileResponse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', '5000')
```

My index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.fileDownload.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
    </head>


<body>
    <a href="/filesfordl/file.txt" class="fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience">Get file!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally JS part:

```
/*$.fileDownload('/filesfordl/file.txt', {
    successCallback: function (url) {

        alert('You just got a file download dialog or ribbon for this URL :' + url);
    },
    failCallback: function (html, url) {

        alert('Your file download just failed for this URL:' + url + '\r\n' +
                'Here was the resulting error HTML: \r\n' + html
                );
    }
});
*/

$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience", function() {
        $.fileDownload($(this).attr('href'), {
            preparingMessageHtml: "We are preparing your report, please wait...",
            failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again."
        });
        return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
    });
});
```

^^ in this part if I uncomment the upper code, it always triggers failCallback after entering index.html even if I don't click on the link.

After clicking the hyperlink i get this error message (can't post images directly yet):
[this](https://zapodaj.net/images/458f54751280d.png) 
Which ultimately leads to this line in the plugin's code. 
[this](https://zapodaj.net/images/a8bf1eebcf387.png)

EDIT:

I've added some debugging prints on top of the problematic line:

```
console.log($("<div>").html(settings.preparingMessageHtml).dialog);
console.log($("<div>").html(settings.preparingMessageHtml));
```

And output I'm getting after that [is](https://zapodaj.net/images/7325a736e0945.png).
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nevermind, I simply forgot to include jQuery UI files which is the sole reason of my issues, topic can be closed.